# Unable to Scroll Linear Layout by ScrollView tag

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have following xml file for my activity and i've made it scroll able but i'm unable to scroll it

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.first.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="332dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/main_label"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/name_hint"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/address_hint" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/phone_hint"
            android:inputType="phone" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/email_hint"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/dob_hint"
            android:inputType="date" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/martial_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/marrital_label"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/m_radio" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/um_radio" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hobby_label"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/h_cricket" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/h_bookreading" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/h_programming" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/h_gardening" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/h_football" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next1"
            android:layout_width="93dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/b1_text" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

```
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item.

So instead of Framelayout, use any other layout if you would want your content to be scrolled.

Comment: sorry i've updated the question... see the edit, it doesn't work

Comment: @Ahmed, your edited question does not have the closing tag </ScrollView>

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the LinearLayout inside the scrollView, like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.first.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="332dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/main_label"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/name_hint"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/address_hint" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/phone_hint"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/email_hint"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/dob_hint"
        android:inputType="date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/martial_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/marrital_label"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/m_radio" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/um_radio" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hobby_label"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/h_cricket" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/h_bookreading" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/h_programming" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/h_gardening" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/h_football" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next1"
        android:layout_width="93dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/b1_text" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```